# How do you debug a dll targeting .net 3.5 without Attaching to a process manually?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I debug my dll targeting .net 3.5, I have to attach to a process and select the option to debug .net 3.5 code as opposed to 4.0+. Apparently you can't debug both do to some incompatible changes.

Problem is I don't know how to start this process from Visual Studio in a way that I can modify the code while it is running. If I use the attach to process menu option the process has to be already running and changes are not reflected until I stop the process and rebuild the dll. How do I host the process in Visual Studio to debug 3.5 code and gain the extra debugging awesomeness being able to modify code and more easily run a debug session?

I'm using VS 2015.

Comment: you build your application targeting .Net 3.5 (project settings) but when you start debugging it's running as .Net 4.0? what is your original problem?

Comment: maybe with System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() called from somewhere relevant in your DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Hei, I often got this problem. 
If you start another application and want to 'add' the dll to the runtime, please try the following.

Go to your (dll's) project properties -> Debug -> start external program . 
If you need start parameters, you can add them below.

Now when you start the debugger ( with the befor modified config ) the application starts up and the debugger is on. Now you maybe need to start something related to the dll you are debugging to 'hit' a breakpoint & you are able to modify the debugging code.

> When you use 'attach to process', visual studio restrices you to modify
>   the code. If you then want to change something you need to stop the
>   debugger, close all related applications, recompile , start over
>   again.

[image: Start External Programm]

Comment: Start external program never loads my dll, I think because Visual Studio is debugging .net 4.0 code and above with this option. Go to the attach to process menu option and you will see there is a drop down to change this to debug code using 3.5 and below

Comment: @bzuillsmith how is the dll interacting with the application you attaching it to ? 
is it only a class you want to debug, or maybe some forms, which are triggered from the original application ? 

if you are debugging and set a breakpoint to the dlls code, is it full red or is it white in the middle and saying ' breakpoint will not be hit ' ?

Comment: The dll has many entity and service classes that the application requires. It is a dll targeting .NET 3.5 while some other dlls are targeting 4.5.1. I can debug the 3.5 dll by attaching to the process ```debug > attach to process...``` and selecting the option to debug .NET 3.5 code and below. But with that method, I lose some of the capability to modify code on the fly that I get when I debug .NET 4.0 code using the ```start external program``` option you describe. So the problem is, ```start external program``` doesn't have a .NET 3.5 option